# VMware上のDebian10で、リンクローカルアドレスを割り当てる方法

Tags: debian, vmware

## 環境

以下のゲストOSは、同一のハードウェアで切り替えて動作させています。
ホストOS：Windows11　Pro
ゲストOS1：Ubuntu　22.04
ゲストOS2：Debian10

ホストPCにUSB-LANを取り付け、VMwareに接続して、あるネットワークに参加します。
DHCPサーバーがない場合には、AutoIPにて、各参加ノードはリンクローカルアドレスを取得します。

## ゲストOS1でのifconfig

```shell
$ ifconfig
br-8e06ace9729f: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.22.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.22.255.255
        ether 02:42:26:4e:91:9f  txqueuelen 0  (イーサネット)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

br-96e9d330e10d: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.18.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.18.255.255
        ether 02:42:b5:76:bf:a3  txqueuelen 0  (イーサネット)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

docker0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
        ether 02:42:2a:e0:77:8d  txqueuelen 0  (イーサネット)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

ens33: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.12.130  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.12.255
        inet6 fe80::b539:b853:51e5:5e85  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:0c:29:f8:4d:e1  txqueuelen 1000  (イーサネット)
        RX packets 2834  bytes 3681360 (3.6 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1250  bytes 130220 (130.2 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enx18c2bfe9e38d: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 169.254.225.246  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 169.254.255.255
        ether 18:c2:bf:e9:e3:8d  txqueuelen 1000  (イーサネット)
        RX packets 38  bytes 2239 (2.2 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 4  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 16  bytes 2570 (2.5 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (ローカルループバック)
        RX packets 229  bytes 25033 (25.0 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 229  bytes 25033 (25.0 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

## ゲストOS2でのifconfig

```shell
$ ifconfig
br-7f1fee163d9c: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.18.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.18.255.255
        ether 02:42:64:68:7a:d7  txqueuelen 0  (イーサネット)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

docker0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
        ether 02:42:45:81:92:93  txqueuelen 0  (イーサネット)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

ens33: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.12.138  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.12.255
        inet6 fe80::20c:29ff:fe54:ba3f  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:0c:29:54:ba:3f  txqueuelen 1000  (イーサネット)
        RX packets 430  bytes 452968 (442.3 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 199  bytes 17163 (16.7 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enx18c2bfe9e38d: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 18:c2:bf:e9:e3:8d  txqueuelen 1000  (イーサネット)
        RX packets 28  bytes 1762 (1.7 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 3  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (ローカルループバック)
        RX packets 16  bytes 960 (960.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 16  bytes 960 (960.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

## 症状

「enx18c2bfe9e38d」というのがUSB-LANです。
Ubuntuでは、正常に
inet 169.254.225.246 という割り当てが行われます。
しかし、Debianでは、アドレスが割り当てられません。

## やってみたこと

以下の記事を見つけたので、試したのですが、動作しまえせん。ifconfigで対象デバイスが表示されなくなってしまいました。
[Linuxにリンクローカルアドレスをアサインして DNS-SD/SSDPを使ってガサる](https://qiita.com/yasuoohno/items/d068df2dc8aa30da7ed7)